# Troubles to access exposed(by docker) port on remote server(GCE)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, port

Google compute engine. fresh ubuntu 18.04.

I run webserver docker container with docker-compose.

```
web:
  image: hitalos/laravel:latest
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    DB_HOST: db
    DB_DATABASE: dbname
    DB_USERNAME: username
    DB_PASSWORD: p455w0rd
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    # with mysql
    MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
    MYSQL_USER: username
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: p455w0rd
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p455w0rd
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  links:
      - db:db
  ports:
      - 8080:80
  environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p455w0rd
```

I can access my app via http://my.remote.host.ip.
But i can't access phpmyadmin by http://my.remote.host.ip:8080. , but i can fetch phpmyadmin page html by bash:

```sh
curl localhost:8080
```

I new in this. Please help me to find out what to do.

Comment: the problem is not docker but phpmyadmin forbidding connections to anything but localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i realised, that configuration was correct by trying it on another cloud service. I think Google compute engine is somehow blocking those ports by default.